# iptables: can't open tcp port

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm running a Raspberry PI B+: Linux pi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

The Raspberry is connect via lan (dhcp. ip: 192.168.78.29) to the local network. I'm trying to open a tcp port (5556) using iptables, in order to send data from a server within the same local network (connected via fritz.box router) to the Raspberry via this port, but I'm constantly failing. I've read several questions here and on the internet, but the client running on the Raspberry does not received any data.

**Does anybody has a hint what might be the problem?**

A short test via telnet shows it is not working (or is this the wrong way to check?).

```
~$ telnet 192.168.178.29 5556
Trying 192.168.178.29...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.178.29: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote hos
```

My iptables entries look like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [140:13492]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp --destination-port 5556 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

After editing this entries I've loaded them

```
sudo iptables-restore /etc/network/iptables
```

Comment: "Connection refused" often means "Connection to that system is allowed, but there is nothing listening on that port". Does `netstat -t -a -n|grep 5556` show anything?