# Opening port in iptables

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, nmap

I tried `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT` to open a port but still closed:

```
$ nmap hostname -p 4444
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-23 04:47 +0430
Nmap scan report for linux (127.0.1.1)
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.1.1: Linux.domain.linux

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4444/tcp closed krb524

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
```

What might the reason be? What should I do instead?

Comment: Is there something *listening* on port 4444?

Comment: It seems to me that you’re in over your head with Kali.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Take a look at a previous discussion this community had regarding Kali: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241897/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for helping me. I tried `nmap hostname -p 4444` but it still says that port is closed

Comment: Perhaps (https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=4444) you wanted to start metasploit first?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, oh come on, `iptables` works exactly the same in all Linuxes. There's nothing distro-specific here, or is there?

Comment: Related/duplicatish: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168925/170373

Comment: You’re right about iptables, @ilkkachu , but I do suspect something disto-specific is going on, based on Kali + port 4444 being for metasploit (based on the speedguide link I Googled above).

Answer (score 2):

There has to be something listening on the port, opening the firewall alone doesn't open it.

Here httpd is listening on 80, so it shows open

```
$ nmap localhost -p 80

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-22 19:22 MDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds
```

Here netstat shows I'm listening on 80, because httpd is listening on it.

```
$ netstat --listening --numeric-ports | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 [::]:80                 [::]:*                  LISTEN

$ systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-22 18:18:01 MDT; 1h 5min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
 Main PID: 1279 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
    Tasks: 7
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─1279 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─1928 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─1929 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─1930 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─1931 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─1932 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─1933 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 22 18:17:55 trogdor.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTT...
May 22 18:18:01 trogdor.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If I shut down httpd:

```
# systemctl stop httpd 
$ nmap localhost -p 80

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-22 19:23 MDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

Netstat shows I'm not listening on 80, even though it's open

```
$ netstat --listening --numeric-ports | grep 80
$
```

The point is, the IPTables part is an [XyProblem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem%22XyProblem%22). If I start a reverse-connect listener on 4444, (this is taken from the [rapid7 Q&A](https://kb.help.rapid7.com/discuss/599b6461d6383b0039d7fbbd)), then port 4444 shows as open and listening and I never have to touch IP tables.

```
msf > use exploit/multi/handler
msf exploit(handler) > set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
msf exploit(handler) > set LHOST 127.0.0.1
msf exploit(handler) > set LPORT 4444
msf exploit(handler) > set ExitOnSession false
msf exploit(handler) > exploit -j

# netstat --numeric-ports --listening | grep 4444
tcp        0      0 localhost:4444          0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: `netstat --listening --numeric-ports | grep 4444` no result

Comment: What do you expect to have running on port 4444

Comment: metasploit but is that matters what I want to run on 4444??